# How to create (functional) onclick button from database generated items?

Tags: javascript, php, html

*@olafmoriarty,
Thanks again for solving this first bit. You were spot on with it.
The one thing I discovered now after playing with it, is that your solution links it to the Todo ID.
But I need the solution to be conditional to the Status of an Todo Item.
i.e.:*

- If Status_ID = 3(Finished) --> Then it should strikethrough the Todo
  Item + attributes. If not --> show alert pop-up of "Unfinished"
- In addition that first part, I would like it to be able to when
  clicked on the "Finished Task" button --> to also place that item in
  the bottom of the showed list of items.
- And as final addition
  **(does not need to be answered here, but just so you know my intent)** --> I am going to try and figure out a way to
  have it save the CSS effects(strikethrough & moving it to the bottom), so it remains when you go off the page
  and back. But that is something I need to think through first before even considering help on it.

*You can find the index.php (including the code from before and the my edited version of your solution given in the hopes of having it do what I want) in this link:* https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-matsumoto-bsxuk?file=/index.php

*If for these (first 2) points you require anything else, do let me know. But I think this is all you need.*

**<<------------------------->> This below part is answered:**

I am trying to create a button function which strikesthrough a "todo item" when clicked on it.
Now the problem I am having is that everywhere I google, no solutions ever mention doing this with database generated items (I might be searching wrong).

So far I have the below bit working, which gives me a button (shown in image) which does not have a function behind yet. Can anyone send me in the right direction?
First time making such buttons with a database behind it.

[todo Item example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y12GO.png)

Comment: _"First time making such buttons with a database behind it."_ - Its not relevant where that button gets its content from. Its just a regular button.

Comment: I tried a few button creations I googled. But I could not get any of them connected to the generated items (at least not working). I can go back in my attempts and share them here if that might help you show me where I went wrong?

Comment: Your PHP script generates markup. It's just a regular page. Any of the regular functions to add an event will work. If it doesn't work for you then add your attempt as a [mcve] and explain the problem you have with that (including any error messages you see in the console)

Comment: Alright, well thank you for responding. I'll keep trying then, if it's solvable with regular functions.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? How is this related to Javascript or CSS, while you haven't shared any such code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code example, you have a button which, when clicked, fires the function `finishedTask()`. If your database table had only one row, that would be enough - but since it probably doesn't, it's not enough to tell the javascript "The task is finished". You also have to tell it *which* task is finished, so that your function knows which row to strike out.

The simplest way to solve that is probably to pass a unique identifier as a parameter to your function, and then add the same identifier to the div so that the function recognizes it as the element to strike out.

This can be achieved by replacing your `printf` statement with something like:

```
printf('<div id="%s">Todo %s: %s<br /> Colour: %s<br /> Status %s:  %s<br /> Priority %s: %s<br /><button onclick="finishedTask(%s)">Finished Task</button></div>', $row['id'], $row['id'], $row['task'], $row['colour'], $row['status_id'], $row['status'], $row['priority_id'], $row['priority'], $row['id']);
```

(The only thing I changed here was adding an `id` attribute to your `div` and changing `finishedTask()` to `finishedTask(%s)`, and filling in the extra printf parameters.)

Then your javascript could look something like this:

```
function finishedTask(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).classList.add("finished");
}
```

(This function doesn't actually strike through the text, it only adds a CSS class to the div that you can style however you'd like.)

As you've already been informed, it doesn't matter to the javascript whether the code comes from a database or not. Just use a unique element to connect the button to whatever you want the button to change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for this for a while. I nearly had some other (very elaborate) solution... 

But this is way simpler!